# storing 'du' result in a variable

Tags: bash, unix, putty

I am using Putty with bash-4.2. Therein, I am outputting file size with:

du -m myfile.csv

which returns:

1.25 myfile.csv

How do i store this line in a variable so I can later parse out the filesize?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the native shell builtin `varname=$(du -m myfile.csv)`

Comment: You should read up on [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so

```
FOO="$(du -m myfile.csv)"
echo "$FOO"
```

Output

```
1.25 myfile.csv
```

Comment: awesome. I appreciate it